# Comment id format has changed?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Did the format of the UID for comments on video posts has changed? We are noticing examples of comments that previously had one id via api, and are now coming back with a different id. This is causing us to save duplicate data, because we can't programmatically determine that they are the same comment.

The issue appeared start approximately Dec 5, 2017.

Example - these two comments appear to be the same comment, just sent twice with different ids. The "external id" below is the youtube UID:

```
title    Comment from nah28
link    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1pRzwFf1lo&lc=z233st5hoofjvbl5f04t1aokglljav4mscz3jhkng02qrk0h00410
publishedDate    2017-11-16 20:14:31
dateFound    2017-11-16 20:16:38
externalId    z233st5hoofjvbl5f04t1aokglljav4mscz3jhkng02qrk0h00410

title    Comment from nah28
link    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1pRzwFf1lo&lc=UgyMXm2SWEfG9sJsAK14AaABAg
publishedDate    2017-11-16 20:14:31
dateFound    2017-12-06 12:17:58
externalId    UgyMXm2SWEfG9sJsAK14AaABAg
```

Comment: If the format has changed, is it intentional or a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Confirm!
I didn't find any changelists related, but we're using comment IDs to uniquely identify comments, and now we're having duplicates of comments of tracked videos.

I wonder if there's a way to obtain somehow old comment id